# img src not working in android browser

Tags: android, html, image, android-browser

I have a simple question.

ex)

```
<div class="myclass">
<img src="http://path/to/image.jpg">
</div>
```

In iOS and desktop browsers are good.
but android browser not working a img tag.
This img tag is not connect with any JavaScript or even CSS.
pure HTML code.
I have no idea.
please help me.

Comment: What if you close the `img` tag? i.e.: `<img src="http://path/to/image.jpg" />`

Comment: Post a link to your Web page that is giving you these results.

Comment: Why did you accept that wrong answer?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You forgot the endtag `</img>`.
Or in one line `<img src="http://path/to/image.jpg" />`

Comment: Thank you. but i find another solution.

Comment: The `<img>` tag has an empty content model and so an end tag is explicitly wrong (in HTML).